# c++ how to detect an char element in a matrix

Tags: c++

Heyo,

I' am writing a game for my uni project, and can't get a piece of my code to detect if they completed the game correctly. The game is https://brainbashers.com/abcview.asp (https://www.brainbashers.com/showabcview.asp?date=1206&which=3). I am checking if there are only 1 A, only 1B, only 1 C in a line/column. Checked it and it does not detect the letter written. Does Anyone have some ideas?

````
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 3; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (gamefield[i][j] == 'A')
                a++;
            else if (gamefield[i][j] == 'B')
                b++;
            else if (gamefield[i][j] == 'C')
                c++;
        }
        if (a == 1 || b == 1 || c == 1)
        {

        }
        else {return false; }
        a = 0; b = 0; c = 0;
    }
    a = 0; b = 0; c = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 3; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (gamefield[j][i] == 'A')
                a++;
            else if (gamefield[j][i] == 'B')
                b++;
            else if (gamefield[j][i] == 'C')
                c++;
        }
        if (a == 1 || b == 1 || c == 1)
        {

        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        a = 0; b = 0; c = 0;
    }```
````

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @NathanOliver, The code itself launches, tho it does not detect the letter. the code rn is 605 lines long, thought asking here would help with that.

Comment: I can add the whole code here if it would provide any help.

Answer (score -3):

can you try to use the ASCII values of the letter instead of the letter itself,
for example to verify if a letter equals 'A' you would write :

```
if (gamefield[j][i] == 65)
```

Comment: You would _not_ write that unless you are a complete beginner.  Do not use magic constants like `65` when you mean `'A'`.

Comment: Uhm, it's already (char)65, so I don't think that would change anything

Comment: `'A'` in the source code will always be `'A'`.  It doesn't mater what character set the implementation is using.  **Don't** use magic numbers.

Comment: Even if the character set is known to be ASCII, the character literal `'A'` is much more meaningful than 65.  As such its usage is more self-documenting and causes less chaotic neural activity in whoever has to read the code.  Feel free to disagree a second time.  Maybe you haven't had to deal with software projects containing millions of code lines before.